# How do I wait for a webelement to disappear?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am testing an app which has a page on which are displayed a number of various fruits. I need to narrow them down by weight. Submitting the weight range triggers an AJAX call, which brings up a loading indicator that covers the whole page until the call returns successfully. Here is my failing code:

```
 public MyPageObject InputWeightRange( int weight, int range = 1000 )
        {
            var page = PageFactory.InitElements<MyPageObject>(Driver);
            var wait = new WebDriverWait( Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 ) );
            wait.Until( driver => page._loadingIndicator.Displayed.Equals( false ) );
            _upperWeight
                .SendKeys( ( weight + ( range/2 ) ).ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) ); //CultureInfo declarations to keep ReSharper happy.
            _lowerWeight.SendKeys( ( weight- ( range/2 ) ).ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) );
            wait.Until(driver => page._loadingIndicator.Displayed.Equals(false));
            wait.Until( driver => page._submitButton.Enabled );
            _submitButton.Click();
            wait.Until(driver => page._loadingIndicator.Displayed.Equals(false));
            return this;
        }
```

Usually, the code works. Sometimes it fails on the click, I think because the loading indicator is also triggered by other actions I'm performing on the page before this. As you can see, I'm using WebDriverWait, but it doesn't work for some reason. I have never in manual testing seen the loading indicator appear for more than half a second.

The actual exception is:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1234, 400). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loadingIndicator" class="loadingIndicator" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

EDIT:
Note that the element is always present in the DOM, so waiting for Enabled just results in WebDriverTimeout exceptions. Other than littering my code with try/catches or thread.sleeps, how can I test this page in safety from exceptions?

Comment: If the loading indicator has any height/width attribute, then try waiting for it to be zero or the dimensions when it is not covering the full page

Comment: That did it, thanks. Could you post that as an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the loading indicator has any height/width attribute, then try waiting for it to be zero or the dimensions when it is not covering the full page

Comment: This wasn't actually quite correct but it put me on the right track; I ended up using loadingIndicator.GetCssValue() on the attribute that was changing.